# Google maps - Places search box :: trigger places_changed event on button click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using **google Places search box**. I have a button next to it. I need to initiate the search  when the button is clicked.

I tried the below code but it's not working for me.

```
    $('#plotMarker').click(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(searchBox, 'places_changed');
    });
```

I want that when the button is clicked, get the same result as when hitting enter ,like how we see on maps.google.com , the search is done when hitting Enter or when clicking the button.